# Rails is there a way to manage a ordered list? so that each item has a position, and if an element is deleted the positions automatically update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Given the following:

ListItem (position, title)

```
1,hello
2,hello2
3,hello3
4,hello4
5,hello5
```

If the 3rd item, 3,hello3 was deleted, is there a way for the positions to automatically update, ie, position 5 would now be position 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at ranked-model: https://github.com/mixonic/ranked-model. I've used it with success on a Rails 3 app and it was very easy to set up.

Comment: +1; didn't know about this one, and it looks enough nicer than my in-house version--cool!

Answer (score 0):

There's also this gem which is very popular.

https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list